# ClassCastException while trying to cast Object to MapEntry

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to get some values from a JSONObject into a HashMap, but I keep getting ClassCastException on the last row of my for loop.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

I've tried to explicitly cast mapEntry.getValue() to integer but I keep getting the same error. if I run the code without the last line I get the following output:

```
key: peter value: 33
key: somekey value: 11
key: steve value: 38
key: guy value: 22
key: name value: 54
```

So I can see that mapEntry.getValue() seems to print integers, or at the very least numbers that I should be able to cast to integers.

```
JSONObject json = getJsonFromFile(filePath);
HashMap<String, Integer> entries = new HashMap<>();

for (Object obj : json.entrySet()) {
            Entry<String, Integer> mapEntry = (Entry<String, Integer>) obj;
            System.out.println("key: " + mapEntry.getKey() + " value: " + mapEntry.getValue());
            entries.put(mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: What is the actual type of `obj` ?

Comment: I'm explicitly casting it to Entry<String, Integer>, its just what I use to be able to iterate through the entrySet, not sure if there are better ways but this seemed to work well untill this bug appeared.

Comment: What happens if you try to use Entry<String, Long> instead?

Comment: It wont compile, compiler thinks mapEntry.getValue() is an integer somehow, but it seems to be a Long.. I really cant get my head around this..

Comment: If you replace all 3 occurrences of <String, Integer> with <String, Long> it will not compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this:

```
JSONObject json = getJsonFromFile(filePath);
HashMap<String, Number> entries = new HashMap<>();

for (Object obj : json.entrySet()) {
    Entry<String, Number> mapEntry = (Entry<String, Number>) obj;
    System.out.println("key: " + mapEntry.getKey() + " value: " + mapEntry.getValue());
    entries.put(mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());
}
```

`Number` is the superclass of both `Integer` and `Long`, it should compile fine.

Comment: Ah, ofcourse! this solves my issue, I'm still unsure as to why I got my error in the first place but I will use this solution until I can find a reason to the weird(in my opinion) behavior.